# What kind of guitar is used in Edenbridge's guitar solos?

Tags: electric-guitar

[Edenbridge](http://edenbridge.org/)'s guitar solos have a unique, almost peaceful sound to them. I am curious, what kind of guitar is used to play them?

[Here is an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B014QMnN2r4&t=05m21s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sound in the track you linked to is not really dependent on the guitar - I can get that noise with a Les Paul, and Ibanez or a Charvel just as easily. What you will need is the right guitar effects. It sounds like they are using:

- long reverb
- digital delay
- tube overdrive
- compressor / noise gate

Comment: In the example video it sounds to me like it's being played on a guitar that has a humbucker in the neck position, given the darker harmonics compared to a bridge pickup (I get the same kind of vibe from John Petrucci's playing when he switches to the neck pickup).  But generally, yes, this sound is not difficult to attain.